# Java EE 8 Web Application with TomCat 8.5 - No documentation in Intellij Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc, tomcat8, java-ee-8

I am working on a projet with Java EE 8 and Tomcat 8.5. My IDE is Intellij Ultimate.

I can't have any documentation with librairies from Tomcat.
For example with javax.servlet, Intellij show no documentation.

Is it possible to add this documentation in my projet ?

Thanks for your help.

Bruno

I try to find documentation for javax.servlet in Intellij Ultimate for a projet with JavaEE and Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You may open library in "Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies", click on plus with a globe ("Specify documentation URL") and add URL to documentation (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/package-summary.html)
Or download documentation manually and add it using plus button.